# I want to add numeric values of two text boxes in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add values of two text boxes and store both textbox values,sum into mysql database table using php as the code below

```
        <?php
    //Include Database
    include 'db.php';
    $data = new Databases;
    $msg = '';
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
     $insert_data = array(
     'first' => mysqli_real_escape_string($data->con, $_POST['first']),
     'Second' => mysqli_real_escape_string($data->con, $_POST['Second']),
     );
     if($data->insert('sum', $insert_data))
     {
     $msg = "Inserted Data Successfully!";
     }
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    if(isset($msg))
    {
     echo $msg;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: First and second input have numeric values or text ?

Comment: only numeric values

Comment: try it insted of array  $insert_data = $_POST['first'] + $_POST['Second'];

Comment: where you want to store sum....in column first or second or there is third column with heading sum in mysql database ?

Answer (score 2):

try this one instead of array.

```
  $sum = $_POST['first'] + $_POST['Second'];
  if($data->insert('sum',$sum)){
   $msg = "Inserted Data Successfully!";
  }else{
   $msg = "Inserted Data Successfully!";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Example Below

```
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $first => mysqli_real_escape_string($data->con, $_POST['first']);
        $second => mysqli_real_escape_string($data->con, $_POST['Second']);
        $insert_data = $first + $second ; // sum of two number
        if($data->insert('sum', $insert_data))
        {
            $msg = "Inserted Data Successfully!";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Include Database
include 'db.php';
$data = new Databases;
$msg = '';

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $first = $_POST['first'];
    $Second = $_POST['Second'];

    $total =  $first+$Second;

    $insert_data = array('total' => mysqli_real_escape_string($data->con, $total));

    if($data->insert('sum', $insert_data)) {
        $msg = "Inserted Data Successfully!";
    }

}

if(isset($msg)) {
    echo $msg;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try :
Assuming you have three columns in mysql table viz. `'first'`, `'second'` and `'sum'`

```
<?php
//Include Database
include 'db.php';
$data = new Databases;
$msg = '';
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
     $first =mysqli_real_escape_string($data->con, $_POST['first']);
     $second = mysqli_real_escape_string($data->con, $_POST['Second']);
     $sum = $first+$second;

    $insert_data = array(
       'first' => $first,
       'Second' => $second,
       'sum' => $sum
     );
    $inserted = $data->insert('sum', $insert_data);
    if ($inserted)
     {
      $msg = "Inserted Data Successfully!";
     }
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($msg))
{
 echo $msg;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thankq Dr Manish Joshi